# MS SQL passing parameter to stored proc indicating value is null or not null

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

need to build a stored procedure which returns data.
On the client I have a checkbox which is used to choose if one value should be null or not.

Let us say the column-name is package.

```
Create PROCEDURE [dbo].[up_query_wt_paketsuche]
(
    @packagenull int = 0 
)
AS
(
SELECT * FROM PACKAGES  
where ???
)
```

So I pass 1 as @packagenull if the query should return all values with packages not null and nothing if the query should return all values where package is null. The main point is to handle the parameter in the where clause. 
The real stored procedure is more complex, 12 parameters, union over two tables... So I would like to handle the parameter in the where clause.

Thanks.

Edit:
My tables are not single tables.
Here is my actual where clause without @packagenull

```
where f.vtyp6maske like @vtyp 
and f.marke like @marke 
and h.mkb like @mkb 
and (
      modjahr_von = @modelljahrvon 
    or 
        (     @modelljahrvon=999999 
        and (modjahr_von is null or modjahr_von is not null)
        )
     ) 
and (modjahr_bis = @modbis 
        or  (
               @modelljahrbis = 999999 
               and (modjahr_bis is null or modjahr_bis is not null)
             )
    ) 
and i.prnr like @prnr
```

Comment: Your `Where` clauses are scary , inefficient and pretty much redundant, this means nothing to sql server `modjahr_von is null or modjahr_von is not null`  but sql server will have to do a lot of work to check the condition anyway.

Answer (score 1):

If i understand you correctly you want ALL or NONE of the rows based on the parameter. This should suffice.

```
Create PROCEDURE [dbo].[up_query_wt_paketsuche]
(
    @packagenull int = 0 
)
AS

SELECT * FROM PACKAGES  
where @packagenull is NULL or someColumn = @packagenull



where f.vtyp6maske like '%' + @vtyp + '%'                            --Added concat here
and f.marke like '%' + @marke + '%' and h.mkb like '%' + @mkb + '%'  --Added concat here
and (modjahr_von = @modelljahrvon or
(@modelljahrvon=999999 and 
(modjahr_von is null or modjahr_von is not null))) 
and (modjahr_bis = @modbis or (@modelljahrbis = 999999 
and (modjahr_bis is null or modjahr_bis is not null))) 
and i.prnr like '%' + @prnr + '%'                                    --Added concat here 
and (@packagenull is null or package = @packagenull)                 --Added additional parameter
```

Comment: After reading the OP question again, I think they want results either way. Re-read the first sentence under the procedure.

Comment: I modified my question with one of my where clauses. Hope it makes it easier to understand my problem. Need to add the @packagenull parameter

Answer (score 0):

@scsimon Sorry, I don't get the meaning. @packagenull is an optional parameter, so it is never null, it is 0 by default. package = @packagenull will never be true, because package is never 0 or 1, it is a string. What I want is package != null when @packagenull=1 and package = null when @packagenull=0

Comment: An optional parameter does NOT mean the value can't be null. It means that you have provided a default value when the parameter is omitted. If you pass the parameter and the value is NULL then your default will be ignored.

Comment: In the code, I don't proivide a value, so the two options are 0 or 1. So as I said already, 0 or 1, nothing else. Null ist not an option, default = 0.